# Duplicate features error in QGIS, I can't create new fields from shapefile layer

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I've had the same problem. Sometimes when I create points from table (.xls), sometimes when I create a new polygon, I can't text to fields (ex. a field with character name). More, when I texted to the fields, then saved, then close Attribute table, and reopen it, everything was gone! It's very stranges! It showed that: "Duplicate feature". I captured some images to you.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.